# Umlauts on Sierra on English keyboard with Alt combo not working anymore for all

Tags: keyboard

Before Sierra:
Alt + O/A/U pressed then shortly afterwards O/A/U -> Ö/Ä/Ü

With Sierra:
Alt + O/A/U pressed then shortly afterwards O/A/U -> works only for ü
 with Alt + o -> ø, Alt + a -> å and pressing the key again leads only to normal letter

Comment: You should add your (logical) keyboard layout and did you install a tool like Karabiner. The common behavior of the logical us/uk keyboard layout is: alt-u & u = ü, alt-u & a = ä and alt-u & o = ö -  in Sierra as well as older system versions.

Comment: Alright - works. I was confused since I had Karabiner (now no longer working - instead only rudimentary Karabiner elements successor) with mapping Alt-Letter = Umlaut. So I thought (since Alt+u = ü) this is system-built-in. But forgot that I now have to use ALWAYS Alt-u+Letter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default key combo in Sierra and older OS Xces on UK/US (physical and logical) keyboards to enter Umlauts is:

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>: ä
<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>: ö
<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>: ü

You probably had a key modifier (like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)) installed in your previous systems and remapped the key combo to get your non-default behavior.

At least Karabiner doesn't work in Sierra currently (as of Oct 2016) and you have to either wait for an update and/or use the old key combo again.

Comment: any other option in the market?